# How are functions called in a Recursive function when there are more than 1 function call in one statement in Python?

Tags: python, recursion, fibonacci

```
def fibonacci(n):

    if n == 0 or n == 1: # base c a s e s
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)

print(fibonacci(10))
```

When fibonacci(10) is called , is fibonacci(n-1) resolved first till the base case and after that,fibonacci(n-2) is resolved?

Comment: You could find out by adding print(‘fibonacci ‘ + str(n)) at the top of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=evaluation%20order#evaluation-order):

> Python evaluates expressions from left to right.

So yes, the evaluation order for `fibonacci(n-2) + fibonacci(n-1)` is as you describe: first `fibonacci(n-2)` is evaluated to a value, then `fibonacci(n-1)` is evaluated to a value, and the entire expression evaluates to the sum of these two values.

There’s nothing special about recursion in this case. Python evaluates left-to-right even if the operands aren’t recursive function calls.